# как отправить json через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему у меня код возвращает пустоту:

```
    var test = '{"1500536354128591697-140-4-709-130969827":{"value":"1500536352145246223-50-1-26193-1898645603"},"1476252684967526706-157-4-26312-181217637":{"value":"1476252684887081320-151-1-26312-2532790135"},"1476252684985803841-159-4-26312-1052842564":{"value":"1476252684887081320-151-1-26312-2532790135"},"1486808888647977659-59-4-582-4256386927":{"value":"1486808888553727044-58-1-582-1794206325"},"1493449722500199519-187-4-709-3016271615":{"value":"1493449708210015275-145-1-26193-4061830634"},"1477640042446460021-164-4-26341-378056455":{"value":"1477640042385839468-158-1-26341-511999530"},"1482841748690991909-87-4-582-2966223399":{"value":"1482841748582930127-86-1-582-755784562"},"1476941827335692438-100-4-582-657711144":{"value":"1476941827183313507-73-1-582-3215889431"},"1477640042435309689-162-4-26341-3795155381":{"value":"1477640042385839468-158-1-26341-511999530"}}';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: test,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

index.php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите кавычки `'` в `var test`. Потому что вы отправляете как текст а не `json`

```
var test = {"1500536354128591697-140-4-709-130969827":{"value":"1500536352145246223-50-1-26193-1898645603"},"1476252684967526706-157-4-26312-181217637":{"value":"1476252684887081320-151-1-26312-2532790135"},"1476252684985803841-159-4-26312-1052842564":{"value":"1476252684887081320-151-1-26312-2532790135"},"1486808888647977659-59-4-582-4256386927":{"value":"1486808888553727044-58-1-582-1794206325"},"1493449722500199519-187-4-709-3016271615":{"value":"1493449708210015275-145-1-26193-4061830634"},"1477640042446460021-164-4-26341-378056455":{"value":"1477640042385839468-158-1-26341-511999530"},"1482841748690991909-87-4-582-2966223399":{"value":"1482841748582930127-86-1-582-755784562"},"1476941827335692438-100-4-582-657711144":{"value":"1476941827183313507-73-1-582-3215889431"},"1477640042435309689-162-4-26341-3795155381":{"value":"1477640042385839468-158-1-26341-511999530"}};
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: test,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо помогли.

Comment: @newProgrammer Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2):

Отправляя запрос таким образом, вы пересылаете JSON в теле POST-запроса, чтобы получить его на сервере читайте поток `php://input` вот так:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($json);
```